# Can not load some modules in deno

Tags: javascript, deno

I just started learning deno and I have already faced "bug like" problems.

When I import oak module to my deno app, it compiles successfully; but when I load mongo or bcrypt, it crashes and shows me this error.

`error: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)`

```
export { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
export { init, mongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo/mod.ts";
```

Here first line is executed correctly, but the second line throws an error.

Comment: I believe it's `MongoClient` not `mongoClient` (just reading the referenced ts files...)

Comment: tried that and got same result

Comment: Did you read the README at https://deno.land/x/mongo? Deno has to be run in unstable mode...

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question

Comment: The README of the Mongo module you're trying to use, which has instructions on how to use the Mongo module you're trying to use, has nothing to do with your question about how to use the Mongo module?

Comment: It's not about how to use mongo module. It's about that error which is thrown every time i import smtp-client, mongodb, bcrypt and loads of other modules. It's not about  just MONGO.

Comment: Ah, so the only example you've included is the example of mongo, and people should just know because of the two words "or bcrypt", that you're talking about more than that. Got it. It might be worth [edit]ing your question...

Comment: mongo or bcrypt means that it's problem of deno and not mongo.

Comment: @ShotikoTopchishvili Can you please post the command by which you are running this code snippet?

Comment: deno run -A --unstable app.js

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use this line

```
export { init, MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo/mod.ts";
```

instead of

```
export { init, mongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo/mod.ts";
```

Then reload the cache by running this command:

```
deno cache --reload --unstable app.js
```

Then run by using this command:

```
deno run -A --unstable app.js
```

Comment: Nope, that's a bug in a deno. https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6022